# Terraform + AWS: key/pair and provisioner not executing when re-scaling instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Below im creating two instances..which work fine the first time.  However, if i update my config variable to change inst2 from t2 to t3.micro, then do a `terraform apply`, the previous instance is destroyed then a new instance is recreated.  However, two things are not happening:

1. the Key-pair is not getting regenerated or applied to the re-scaled instance
2. and i believe because of this, the provisioner is not able to execute

I say this because im not able to ssh into the box unless i either manually edit by ~/.ssh/config.  if do that i can get into the newly created instance, but i do not see any of the bootstrapped installion on this re-scaled instance.

Anyone run into this issue and know how i can resolve this?

here is my config vars:

```
locals {
  instances= {
    i1= {
      size = "t2.micro",
      ami           = data.aws_ami.ami_default.id,
      auth      = module.ec2.keypair_id,
      region    = "us-east-1a",
      user_data     = "bootstrap.tpl",
    }
    
    i2= {
      size = "t2.micro",
      ami           = data.aws_ami.ami_default.id,
      auth      = module.ec2.keypair_id,
      region    = "us-east-1b",
      user_data     = "bootstrap.tpl",
    }
  }
}
```

and here is the snippet that creates the key pair as well as instances:

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "auth" {
  key_name   = "auth"
  public_key = file("${var.key_pair}.pub")
}
    
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  for_each               = var.instances
  size          = each.value.size
  ami                    = each.value.ami
  key_name               = aws_key_pair.auth.id
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.ec2_security_group.id]
  #security_groups        = [aws_security_group.ec2_security_group]
  subnet_id = var.subnets[each.value.region].id
  user_data = file("userdata.tpl")
    
  #size of drive
  root_block_device {
    volume_size = each.value.vol_size
  }
    
   provisioner "local-exec" {
     command = templatefile("${path.module}/ssh_cfg.tpl", {
       hostname     = self.public_ip,
       user         = "ec2-user",
       identityfile = var.key_pair
     })
     interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
   }
}
```

Comment: What did the plan/apply output say? Did it show anything for the key? Also, I don't know what's inside of the user data, but you might want to set this `user_data_replace_on_change = true`.

Comment: Hi @MarkoE, the user data is simply a boostrap script to install a few components and start them. the contents is not important, but what is - is the reason the provisioner is not getting executed the 2nd time.   i did add your recommendation.  But what made a difference is when i want to update an instance resource, to specifically target that instance instead of doing a generic terraform apply.  So instead if i do this:  ```terraform  apply -replace='module.ec2.aws_instance.instance[\"i1\"]'```, it worked fine.
this apparently is a known issue with terraform

Answer (score 0):

This issue is noted here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/23315

The above link does reference the 'user_data_replace_on_change' setting that @markoE mentioned.  but that alone did not seem to solve my issue.  What i needed to do was to explicitly call the following when i wanted to size up/down my instances to have the userdata scripts invoked a 2nd time

```
terraform  apply -replace='module.ec2.aws_instance.instance[\"i1\"]'
```